# Shopify Api To Filter Products Based On Metafield iOS

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, shopify, shopify-mobile-buy-sdk

I've added a metaField to my Shopify Store that store the location of the Products and Collections. I can fetch the value added to the metafield from my Model class. What I'm trying to do is to filter the products fetched based on the value added to the metaField. I'm not able to find a way to do that.

Below is the ProductModel that I'm using where I'm accessing the metaField value. I'm able to access the value of the metaField this way:

```
import Foundation
import Buy

final class ProductModel: Model {
    
    typealias ModelType = Storefront.Product
    
    let model:    ModelType
    
    let id:       String
    let title:    String
    let summary:  String
    let price:    String
    let images:   PageableArray<ImageModel>
    let variants: PageableArray<VariantModel>
    let storeLocation: String?
    
    // ----------------------------------
    //  MARK: - Init -
    //
    required init(from model: ModelType) {
        self.model    = model
        
        let variants = model.variants.nodes.models.sorted {
            $0.price < $1.price
        }
        
        let lowestPrice = variants.first?.price
        
        self.id       = model.id.rawValue
        self.title    = model.title
        self.summary  = model.descriptionHtml
        self.price    = lowestPrice == nil ? "No price" : Currency.stringFrom(lowestPrice!)
        
        self.images   = PageableArray(
            with:     model.images.nodes,
            pageInfo: PageMetaData(pageInfo: model.images.pageInfo)
        )
                
        self.variants = PageableArray(
            with:     model.variants.nodes,
            pageInfo: PageMetaData(pageInfo: model.variants.pageInfo)
        )
        
        if let metaFieldValue = model.metafield?.value {
            self.storeLocation = metaFieldValue
            BSLog.debugLog("MetaField : \(metaFieldValue)")
        } else {
            self.storeLocation = "No Location"

        }
    }
}
```

Below is how I'm fetching the products:

```
func fetchProducts(with ids: [String], completion: @escaping (PageableArray<ProductModel>?) -> Void) {
        let query = ClientQueryProduct.queryForProducts(with: ids)
        let task  = self.client.queryGraphWith(query) { (query, error) in
            error.debugPrint()
            if let query = query, let results = query.nodes as? [Storefront.Product] {
                let products = PageableArray(
                    with:     results,
                    pageInfo: PageMetaData()
                )
                completion(products)
            } else {
                print("Failed to load products: \(String(describing: error))")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

How I'm querying the product:

```
static func queryForProducts(with ids: [String]) -> Storefront.QueryRootQuery {
        let graphIDs: [GraphQL.ID] = ids.map { GraphQL.ID.init(rawValue: $0) }
        return Storefront.buildQuery { $0
            .nodes(ids: graphIDs) { $0
                .onProduct { $0
                    .fragmentForProduct()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Product Query to fetch the details of the product.

```
extension Storefront.ProductQuery {
    
    @discardableResult
    func fragmentForProduct() -> Storefront.ProductQuery { return self
            .id()
            .title()
            .descriptionHtml()
            .variants(first: 250) { $0
                .fragmentForStandardVariant()
            }
            .images(first: 250) { $0
                .fragmentForStandardProductImage()
            }
            .metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "location") { $0
                    .value()
            }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can filter the products using the metaField value?